# setTimeout don't working with function return Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

Here is my code:

```
exports.test = function() {
  x(1)
}

var x = function(no) {
  var client = new twitter({
    consumer_key: global.twitter_consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: global.twitter_consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: 'token key',
    access_token_secret: 'token key'
  });
  var link_user_show = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=' + 'mahdi_almayali' + '&user_id='
  client.get(link_user_show, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err at check_twitter_username: ', err)
        // reject(err)
    } else {
      // resolve(data.screen_name)
      console.log('x: ', no)
      setTimeout(x(no++), 500000)
    }
  })
}
```

I used `setTimeout` func for `x()` func, but it not working. It will run run run, don't delay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling functions with setTimeout()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)

Comment: Yeah. Correct. I did. Thanks